# open certmgr.msc from commanf line on localMachine

Tags: cmd, certificate, mmc

I need to start "certmgr.msc" from "cmd.exe" on "localMachine" repository so that I can import\export certificates.
I have tried the following commands but the "certmgr.msc" keeps opening on "currentUser".

```
certmgr.msc -s -r localMachine root
mmc.exe certmgr.msc -s -r localMachine root
certmgr.msc -v -s -r localMachine my
```

Comment: If you intend to manage a server via command line, PowerShell is a better option, http://blogs.technet.com/b/scotts-it-blog/archive/2014/12/30/working-with-certificates-in-powershell.aspx

Answer (score 5):

This should do it

```
"C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\MMC.EXE" "C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\CERTLM.MSC"
```

Comment: there is no file named "certlm.msc"

Comment: this file is on windows 8,

Comment: hmm, you are right. But it seems to be portable :). Just take the file from windows 8. Tried it with windows 8.1 and windows 2008 and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Create custom console by adding Certificate snapin and targeting it to local computer. Then save this console to .mmc file. 
You can refer this saved file in command line. Can also distribute this custom console to other machines.

Answer (score 0):

Below should start MMC console with both nodes **CurrentUser** & **Local Computer**

```
certificates.msc
```

Answer (score 0):

```
mmc.exe certlm.msc -s -r localMachine root
```

It should work - Tested on win2012r2